# Getting error while uploading files from ec2 linux to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, amazon-iam

I am trying to copy some files from ec2(linux) to s3 bucket.i attached this policy to my s3

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1487803543981",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1487803541931",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::###234222###:user/Bilkishjain"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:*Multi*",
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>/<filename>"
        }
    ]
}
```

I did aws configure and provided the access keys and access id.but when i tried to use this command:

```
aws s3 mv /home/ec2-user/temp/backup/*.tar.gz s3://s3-bucketname/testfolder/
```

It gives out this error:

```
sudo aws s3 mv /home/ec2-user/temp/backup/debugLogBackup_$(date +%F).tar.gz s3://s3-bucketname/testfolder/debugLogBackup_$(date +%F).tar.gz
move failed: backup/debugLogBackup_2017-02-22.tar.gz to s3://s3-bucketname/testfolder/debugLogBackup_2017-02-22.tar.gz
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied
```

Parameter validation failed:

> Invalid type for parameter UploadId, value: None, type: , valid types:

Can anyone help me with this error?

Comment: Pleae format your question so that everything is easier to read.

Comment: first, make sure IAM user has permission to upload and put objects on the object. Second, are you sure this is interpreted well? "s3:*Multi*"   try to tinker with it a bit, write the permission explicitly and try again.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are [moving](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html) multiple files (with a specific extension) from your local directory to an S3 bucket, your command should be something like this (using [exclude and include filters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)):

```
aws s3 mv /home/ec2-user/temp/backup/ s3://s3-bucketname/testfolder/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.tar.gz"
```

You also have a problem with your policy's `"Resource"` element. Because you are uploading multiple files, it should be in the following format (i.e., using wildcards): `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-bucketname/testfolder/*"`.

**NOTE**: Although you can use one or more wildcards (*) in the action string (see [Specifying Resources in a Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html)), I would strongly advise against that. It is best to use explicit permissions, if possible.

You could try the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1487803543981",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1487803541931",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::###234222###:user/Bilkishjain"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-bucketname/testfolder/*"
        }
    ]
}
```